# Normal maps not working in blender internal in 2.78 update

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, normal-map

I was just wondering because ever since blender 2.78 normal map data would not be displayed in the final render. However it is displayed in GLSL (viewport). Below is an example of said problem.
[image]

[image]

Am I missing a new feature or is this a bug? If this is a bug has anyone else encountered this problem and is it being fixed? I would very much like to use the new features in 2.78 but this problem is really annoying me.

edit: If I check tangent shading the normal data is used. This is strange. Not a  fix but. ..

Comment: In the Image settings (visible in your screen shots), try changing the Color Space from sRGB to Non-Color Data. Does this fix it?

Comment: Thanks, for the reply, I have played around with the color space as well as the image space (i.e. tangent, world...) I have also tried a node setup with the new normal map node with the gamma correction... pretty much from what I can tell normals just won't work in blender internal.

Comment: Oh, my understanding is that you should either use gamma correction or set to Non-Color Data, but not do both. Can you upload the .blend using Blend Exchange?

Comment: @Mentalist I have been using blender for 6 years now, this is the first major problem that I have encountered that there was no documentation for (which is why I am asking in many forums). I cannot find anyone however with similar problems in 2.78. I have been scouring the bug lists  with little avail, I think it might be a system error rather than a bug in blender if no one else is experiencing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I was able to 'fix' this problem. For some reason now in 2.78 your mesh requires a uvmap regardless of whether or not it is using said uvmap (global... genereated .etc.) for normals to work as intended. diffuse spec all work fine without it. So to fix this problem with the normal map not working, all that had to be done was just create a uvmap. Weird but... there you have it.

Comment: Good to know! Thanks for sharing the solution.

Comment: Thank you have been going crazy on this for an hour now!